# Changing visible JPanels in a JFrame from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a class named Window that extends JFrame and sets up the basic layout. To that JFrame I want to add different JPanels and a seperate class named Tracking is deciding which JPanel is being showed in the JFrame. I would like to have the Tracking class being able to change what JPanel is being showed in the JFrame.

Each JPanel is a seperate class, the JFrame and the Tracking class are also seperate classes.

**Window.java**

```
package Setup;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame
{

    private static final int width = 1280;
    private static final int height = 720;

    public Window()
    {
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        frame.setUndecorated(true);
//        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

**Animation.java**

```
package Setup;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Animation extends JPanel
{

    private final int width = super.getWidth();
    private final int height = super.getHeight();
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbGraphics;

    public Animation()
    {
        setSize(width, height);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbGraphics = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbGraphics);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //ADD Animation to get attention from users
        g.drawString("TEST TEST TEST", 50, 50);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: DO NOT call repaint from Winn ANY paint method. You MUST call super.paintXxx as these methods do a lot of extra work and setup to prepare the graphics context appropriately. It is recommended that you use paintComponent to perform all your painting

Comment: I am new to GUIs and painting, I actually got it from a tutorial. Should I replace replaint(); with super.paint(g); ?

Comment: You should remove the call to repaint all together. Move all your code in paint to paintComponent (removing the call to paintComponent) and make sure you're calling super.paintComponent as the the first statement of the method

Comment: Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You have any number of cohoes

### You Could...

Pass a reference of the frame or the controller.  This would then allow you access to all the components on the frame.

This is a bad idea as it would expose the frame to the controller unnecessarily, give he controller more power then it actually needs...

### You Could...

Pass the list of panels to the controller.  This wold allow he controller to change the panels as it required.

This not too bad an idea, but a clever controller would be able to use the getParent method to deduce the top level container, again, exposing parts of your application unnecessarily

### You Could...

Create a simple model that has simple accessors that would allow the controller to the ability to suggest to the UI what views should be active. These could be named, for instances, or you could simply supply `next`/`previous`/`first`/`last` methods to allow the controller to change the view.

This allows you to change the views ordering in a pluggable fashion,simply by supplying a new model, which wouldn't affect any other part of the application

Comment: Thank you very much MadProgrammer! My problem is solved with the help of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/